# HTTP 502, different browsers have different redirect location in response header

Tags: http, browser, http-headers, load-balancing

Our applications are sitting on two servers which has a load balancer in front of it.  The load balancer is over SSL (https) while the server are not. We do SSL offloading. When the user clicks on the load balancer URL, the first HTTP GET response is 502 with a location tag in the response header. This location consists of the URL of the actual page.

The problem is, we are somehow getting the different (possibly wrong?) path in the **Location** header in Chrome and Firefox (both latest version of today). In IE it is working fine.

Example:

LB URL: *https://mywebapp.com/dashboard*

Chrome Firefox Response header location tag:
*http://mywebapp.com/dashboardonserverxyz*

IE Response header location tag:
*/dashboardonserverxyz*

The question: Why is IE giving relative path whereas chrome, firefox gives absolute redirect path in location. Also, which one is the actual one sent by the application server? Since the URL given by Chrome, firefox has http, the users are not able to access the application. I tried clearing cache, resetting browser, uninstalling and reinstalling. Someone the location value is still coming as absolute.

Any help will be much appreciated. FYI: Application is TIBCO Spotfire, Load balancer is F5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the solution in case anyone else faces the same issue.

So this got nothing to do with the browser. It was the cache at the load balancer level (F5). Once we disabled the load balancer caching, the http redirect access came with a relative path.

Comment: I am facing a similar issue. My main app does a redirect which has OpenID Oauth validation flow in between, but upon validation it should redirect to the 2nd app, works fine in IE and Firefox. In Chrome it Transport Header URL is set as my base app. I am glad it worked in your case but that does not explain why the F5 cache would work for IE.